# Integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ on the semicircle from $-i$ to $i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to integrate $\frac{1}{z}$ over the following curve:
[following curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCAMn.png)

This is what I did:

Using the principal analytic branch of $\log(z)$,
$$\int_{-i}^i \frac{1}{z}dz=\log(z)|_{-i}^i = \log|z|+i \arg(z)|_{-i}^i= \left(\log(1)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\right) -\left(\log(1)-i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=i\frac{\pi}{2} + i\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi i.$$

Is this correct? I'm really confused and thus not sure if what I did is correct or not.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I think this works, but for me, a more natural way is to parameterize the path first and arrive at the same answer.

Comment: Why not just integrate over the curve $t \mapsto e^{it}$?

Comment: The final result is correct even without parameterizing the path, but where did you get the $2\pi$ from? I wrote $\left[\log|z|+i\operatorname{arg}(z)\right]_{-i}^{i} = \log|i| + i\arg(i) - \log|-i| - i\arg(-i).$

Comment: @copper.hat If I do that, then $t$ goes from $3\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, right?

Comment: @Accelerator You are correct. I'm going to update my answer

Comment: @panipapas Well, if I understand your diagram correctly, I would say $-{ \pi \over 2}$ to $+{\pi \over 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you could parametrize the curve by $t \mapsto e^{it}$ and then calculate it. However, you know that $1/z$ is continuous on any subset of $\mathbf{C} \backslash \{0\}$, therefore the integral along any path adjoining these two points (not going through $0$) will only depend on the beginning/endpoints. What you have done is therefore correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using parametrized path: $z=e^{it}, (-\pi/2\le t\le \pi/2)$ gives 
$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{e^{it}}(ie^{it}dt)=i\pi$$
is a better approach unless you care much about the behavior of the integrand function at its  (*possible*) singularities. For instance, if the path is rather  the imaginary axis *i.e.* $z=iy,(-\pi/2\le y\le \pi/2)$ then you end up getting 
$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{iy}(idy)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{y}dy$$ which actually diverges as a real integral.